# How to compare strings as int in EAV model

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity-attribute-value

I have implemented an EAV db pattern as part of a poc in postgres. This is the following er illustration:

```
entity:
id, primary key 
firstName, varchar
lastName, varchar
tenantId, int, b-tree indexed

attribute:
id, primary key
label, varchar
type, varchar, (enumerated as string from java enum , NUMERIC, TEXT, DATE)

attribute_value:
id, primary key 
attribute_id, fk reference attribute primary key
entity_id, fk reference entity primary key
value, varchar
```

Now the problem I am facing is while comparing values, in the joined tables.
For example,

```
how do I check whether an attribute with label = 'marks12' has value <
100
```

Comparing the `value::int` does not solve the problem as there are other attribute such as `gender` that cannot be cast into `int` value.
How do I perform such value centric conditions in above eav design model.

PS:I am open to other db design which allows to map/store dynamic attributes in RDBMS.

Comment: Note: entity and attribute should have Primary Keys, too.

Comment: yes, they do. I will update the illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [dynamic command.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) The function should do the job:

```
create or replace function eval_condition(attr text, a_type text, op text, val text)
returns boolean language plpgsql immutable as $$
declare
    result boolean;
begin
    execute format(
        'select %L::%s %s %L::%s',
        attr, a_type, op, val, a_type)
    into result;
    return result;
end $$;
```

Examples:

```
with example(attr, a_type, op, val) as (
values
    ('100',        'int',     '>',    '50'),
    ('2019-01-01', 'date',    '>',    '2019-01-02'),
    ('some text',  'text',    'like', 'some%'),
    ('99.99',      'numeric', '<',    '99.99')
)
select
    attr, a_type, op, val,
    eval_condition(attr, a_type, op, val)
from example;

    attr    | a_type  |  op  |    val     | eval_condition 
------------+---------+------+------------+----------------
 100        | int     | >    | 50         | t
 2019-01-01 | date    | >    | 2019-01-02 | f
 some text  | text    | like | some%      | t
 99.99      | numeric | <    | 99.99      | f
(4 rows)
```